# MySQL: Expression of generated column contains disallowed function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a curious problem with MySQL. Specifically with Stored Procedures and Generated Columns.

**The Problem**

With the Stored Procedure, an exception is thrown:

> Error Code: 3102. Expression of generated column 'unique_name' contains a disallowed function.

However, if I run the query (the stored procedure calls the same query), it works fine. Subsequently, the stored procedure works properly (well, most of the time anyway). What I mean is:

[image: mysql output]

*There were no changes made to the table structure in the time these queries were fired.*

Any help, explanation and advice on this would be really appreciated. Thanks!

**Additional Details**

MySQL version: `5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.10.1 (Ubuntu)`

Table schema:

[image: Table schema]

The Stored Procedure in question:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE createPost
(IN author INT(11), IN title CHAR(100), IN content LONGTEXT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `blog`.`posts` (`author`, `title`, `content`) VALUES (author, title, content); 
    SELECT last_insert_id() as last_insert_id;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

How I call it:

```
CALL createPost('1','223','12');
```

The Expression for the Generated Column (`unique_name`):

```
replace(concat(`title`,'-',`date_time`),' ','_')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failing to make generated columns work, I decided to work around it. Changing the `unique_name` column to non-generated column (prototyping phase, so dropping the table was an option), I decided to create the entry, then update it in the stored procedure, like so:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE createPost
(IN author INT(11), IN title CHAR(100), IN content LONGTEXT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `blog`.`posts` (`author`, `title`, `content`) VALUES (author, title, content);
    UPDATE `blog`.`posts`
    SET `posts`.`unique_name` = replace(concat(`title`,'-',SUBSTR(UUID(),1,8)),' ','_')
    WHERE `posts`.`post_id` = last_insert_id();
    SELECT last_insert_id() as last_insert_id;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

It seems to be working alright now. My best guess is that generated columns don't play nicely with timestamps. Any insight/feedback into the correctness of my approach would still be appreciated. Cheers :)

Comment: It would have been interesting to add the current time as a supplied value with each insert rather than using a default value. My feeling is the virtual  column might have worked. From http://mysqlserverteam.com/virtual-columns-and-effective-functional-indexes-in-innodb/, I learnt that "you cannot create virtual columns on non-repeatable/non-deterministic functions." and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP falls under this category. Seems you were including the function, albeit indirectly, by including a field with that function as a default.